# How to properly convert MongoDB BSON into PHP Object

Tags: php, mongodb, exception, bson

i hope you guys can help me with this:

First things first - i'm using following Version/ Libraries:

- PHP:PHP 7.0.3-1~dotdeb+8.1
- mongodb version => 1.1.2
- Mongo PHPLibrary (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/)

I'm trying to convert the BSON Arrays i get out of the Database to work with in my project.

As i understood one of MongoDBs big opportunities is to have different organized data in one collection.
Like in this example(where only one object has the "description" tag:

JSON Document:

```
{
    enumbers ":[ {
        "id": "84",
        "enumber": "E 472 b",
        "name": "Milchs\u00e4ureester von Mono- und Diglyceriden von Speisefetts\u00e4uren"
    }, {
        "id": "198",
        "enumber": "E 407",
        "name": "Carrageen",
        "description": "Testdescription",
    }, {
        "id": "293",
        "enumber": "E 941",
        "name": "Stickstoff"
    }]
}
```

I'm accessing the Database with following code:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, "test", "items");
$document = $collection->findOne(["id" => '5']);
$product= new Product($document);
```

Works fine till here.

```
use MongoDB\Model\BSONArray;
use MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument;
class Product
public function __construct(BSONDocument $data)
{


    foreach ($data as $part){
        try{
        $this->setId($part->id);
        $this->setEnumber($part->id);
        $this->setName($part->name);
        --------------------------------------
        $this->setDescription($part->description);
        --------------------------------------
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e;
        }

    }

    echo "-------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;

}
```

Now the "$this->setDescription($part->description);" throws an Exception:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Where the "description" Tag is not defined.

Actually i hoped for it returning null where it is not existing.

How do i catch this properly that some of the Datasets may or may not have this tag?

Hope you can help me & thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i tried to access one layer "too deep" in my function. 
When i tried to access

```
$this->setDescription($data->description);
```

i could check if it was set:

```
if (isset($data->name)) $this->setName($data->name);
```

works.

I thought i've tried that already with no result - but i think working on a due thesis contributes to overreading this.

Comment: I would not use this concept anymore. I would now use an Hydrator(-Concept).